# Why am I not receiving deserialized data in my WebAPI?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, serialization

I've got a simple WebAPI app. In my controller I have:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DoSomeWork(string stringParam, DTOObject dto)
{
    // Some work gets done in here
}
```

I've got a console app doing this:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_context);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("ControllerPath/DoSomeWork", new object[]{someString, dtoObject}).Result;
```

I don't receive any errors. When my breakpoint is hit inside of the Controller, it shows the string coming in as NULL and the DTO coming is a fully populated but with default values (1/1/1900s, nulls, etc). I feel like the controller isn't properly deserializing the object but I'm kind of at a loss of how to fix this. Any thoughts?

Comment: a good tool to use in situations like this is Fiddler (free download). It sets itself up as a network proxy and you can see each request and server response. In this case, you'd be more easily able to see the exact data transmitted by your client application.

Comment: This may not be the approach you're looking for, but I typically stick with `string` parameters and `Json.Decode()` and `Json.Encode()` for de/serialization.  I just think it's cleaner.
Also, I suggest returning an HttpResonseMessage from your WebApi Controllers so that you can control the headers (correct response codes, etc.)

Comment: @DiskJunky - I can't use Fiddler in this case because it's on the same box at the moment.

Comment: @jermny ah, then I think wtfsven's approach is the best way forward in trying to diagnose the issue. Try (de)serializing to/from a string to ensure that side of things is working

Answer (score 1):

The solution was because my controller wasn't an ApiController. Once I changed the controller to inherit from ApiController instead of Controller, everything worked without issue.